# Do symbolic integration of function including \[ScriptCapitalL]

Tags: calculus-and-analysis, symbolic, symbols, letter-makes-difference

I have done a symbolic integration in mathematica 13.2 as follow

`Integrate[-((Sqrt[-r(r - 2 l)] l)/(r(r - 2 l) (-r + l))), r] //  Simplify[#, r > 0] &`

`Integrate[-((Sqrt[-r(r - 2 l)] l)/(r(r - 2 l) (-r + l))) /. {l -> \[ScriptL]}, r] // Simplify[#, r > 0] &`

All that I have done is simply the replacement of "l" with "scl", but mathematica gives two very different symbolic outputs

OutPut[1][image]

OutPut[2][image]

Why? Can I use special symbols in integration safely?

Comment: Related: https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/25182/1871 https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/223577/1871 https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/22071/1871 https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/103323/1871 https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/43108/1871  There may be more.

Comment: Definite integrals are more reliable since they cannot differ by a constant but usually slower to compute. However, in V13.3.0, while these produce the same answer, the answer is `Undefined` under the assumptions: `Integrate[-((Sqrt[-r (r - 2 l)] l)/(r (r - 2 l) (-r + l))), {r, 0, r}, Assumptions -> {2 l > r > 0}]` and `Integrate[-((Sqrt[-r (r - 2 l)] l)/(r (r - 2 l) (-r + l))) /. {l -> \[ScriptL]}, {r, 0, r}, Assumptions -> {2 \[ScriptL] > r > 0}]`. This is seems a bug, whereas the different results in the indefinite integrals above I would call unsurprising and not a bug.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I'd call this a bug. I've seen cases where the letter makes difference in result (internally some code seems to use lexicographic ordering in some places? and this have this side effect of changing the expression form which affects some code). So this is not really new in Mathematica. It does  not have to be special character for this to happen. I've put some related links at bottom

Here is a simpler example than your's showing this, also using Rubi to compare

### Mathematica 13.3

```
ClearAll["Global`*"]
integrand1=z/Sqrt[-(r*(r-2*z))]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

```
anti1=Integrate[integrand1,r]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

```
ReImPlot[anti1/.z->2,{r,-Pi,Pi},PlotRange->All]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

Now simply change `z` to `q` in the integrand. Now the anti-derivative is completely different

```
integrand2=integrand1/.z->q
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

You see the integrand is same as before, just `q` instead of `z`

```
anti2=Integrate[integrand2,r]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

```
ReImPlot[anti2/.q->2,{r,-Pi,Pi},PlotRange->All]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

### Rubi

Here changing the letter did not make difference as expected.

```
Quit[]
<<Rubi`
integrand1=z/Sqrt[-(r*(r-2*z))]
anti1=Int[integrand1,r]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

```
ReImPlot[anti1/.z->2,{r,-Pi,Pi},PlotRange->All]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

```
integrand2 = integrand1 /. z -> q
anti2 = Int[integrand2, r]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

```
ReImPlot[anti2 /. q -> 2, {r, -Pi, Pi}, PlotRange -> All]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

**related links**

[Simplification depends on the names of variables](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/226622/simplification-depends-on-the-names-of-variables)

[Why does simplification in Mathematica depend on variable names](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/22071/why-does-simplification-in-mathematica-depend-on-variable-names?rq=1)

[Variable naming changes everything](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/25182/variable-naming-changes-everything)

[Apart behaves differently depending on specific alphabetic letters of variables](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/264589/apart-behaves-differently-depending-on-specific-alphabetic-letters-of-variables)

[DSolve—different solutions for same set of equations using different symbols?](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/103323/dsolve-different-solutions-for-same-set-of-equations-using-different-symbols)

[Evaluating two equivalent integrals apparently gives two different results](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/95374/evaluating-two-equivalent-integrals-apparently-gives-two-different-results)

Comment: Thanks for your helpful reply. I wonder if there are some effective methods or say packages as you have shown, Rubi, to avoid this bug?

Comment: (+1) I would not call this a bug. Variable ordering makes a difference in  symbolic algebra. (Simple example: `Reduce[x < y < x^2 - x - 6, {x, y}]` and `Reduce[x < y < x^2 - x - 6, {y, x}]`.) Obviously, `Integrate[]` cannot know what ordering was used or will be used in the next call to `Integrate[]`. (Maybe it could be improved. For example, parameters after integration variables. That's Daniel's call.)

Comment: @LAIN One does not have even to go `Reduce` for an example. The standard ordering leads to a different coefficient on `r` after simplification: `{-((Sqrt[-r (r - 2 l)] l)/(r (r - 2 l) (-r + l))),
  -((Sqrt[-r (r - 2 l)] l)/(r (r - 2 l) (-r + l))) /. {l -> \[ScriptL]}} // Simplify`. And the different coefficient leads to a different antiderivative. I think that would make it hard to give a consistent result, because it depends on the internal ordering. I doubt WRI would implement a option-defined ordering to be used in sorting `Orderless` functions like `Plus`.

Comment: @MichaelE2 It is true that in indefinite integrals, the difference between two results can often be a constant. However, based on the figures that Nasser has shown, it appears that the difference in the imaginary part is not a constant.

Comment: @LAIN The difference appeared to be locally constant in my tests.